# Styled components mode in Emacs?

Tags: reactjs, emacs, styled-components

I'm using web-mode in Emacs to write my React app, but it lacks support for styled components, no syntax highlighting or indentation for CSS in JS, making it very difficult to use.
Is there any way I can make it work?

Comment: seems vs-code is your friend :)

Answer (score -2):

You can configure all the necessary tools in emacs.

Have a look at `js2-mode` [in the Emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Js2Mode), You will find there links to the repository, for features such as linting and refactoring.

Also [indium](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/Indium) A JavaScript development environment for Emacs.
You will find examples on the github link, and full documentation [here in readthedocs.](https://indium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: they do not support styled-components